# Foundation 5 full-width header image

Tags: css, image, header, width, zurb-foundation

I have the problem on [my homepage](http://us-patriots.hol.es/)

Could you help me please? On very big screens it shows my header image left floated.

```
<div class="row fullWidth">
<img src="img/header.jpg" alt="header-picture"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
.fullWidth{width: 100%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;max-width: initial;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean is that the image is *aligned left* on widescreen monitors.
Do you want it centered or full-width covered?

Then add:

```
.fullwidth img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%; /* just add width in case you want the image covering full-width */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

to your stylesheet.